# How to get relationships with properties from Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

After some struggle to get it right I manage to save relationships with properties to a Neo4j db with Neo4jClient. The problem arrises when I want to read those relationships back. Suddenly the query which worked like a charm before does not return my users anymore? No exceptions are thrown, the call just silently returns empty :( I read about possible deserializing problems and added the parameterless constructor to the relationship class but no luck.

```
public class UserHasHomeCity : Relationship<HasHomeCity>, IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<UserEntity>, IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<CityEntity>
{
    public UserHasHomeCity()
        : base(-1, null)
    {
    }

    public UserHasHomeCity(NodeReference targetNode, HasHomeCity data)
        : base(targetNode, data)
    {
    }

    public const string TypeKey = "USER_HAS_HOME_CITY";
    public override string RelationshipTypeKey
    {
        get { return TypeKey; }
    }
}

public class HasHomeCity
{
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public HasHomeCity()
    { }

    public HasHomeCity(string date)
    {
        this.Date = date;
    }
}
```

And here is my query:

```
     var graphResults = graphClient.Cypher
            .Match("(user:User)-[:USER_IS_IN_ROLE]-(role:Role)",
            "(user:User)-[:USER_HAS_HOME_CITY]-(homeCity:City)-[:CITY_IS_IN_COUNTRY]-(homeCountry:Country)",
            "(user:User)-[:USER_HAS_LIVING_CITY]-(livingCity:City)-[:CITY_IS_IN_COUNTRY]-(livingCountry:Country)")
            .Where((UserEntity user) => user.Id == id)
            .Return((user, role, homeCity, livingCity, homeCountry, livingCountry) => new
            {
                User = user.As<UserEntity>(),
                Roles = role.CollectAs<RoleEntity>(),
                HomeCity = homeCity.As<CityEntity>(),
                LivingCity = livingCity.As<CityEntity>(),
                HomeCountry = homeCountry.As<CountryEntity>(),
                LivingCountry = livingCountry.As<CountryEntity>()
            }).Results;
```

Comment: You don't appear to be returning any of the relationships? I'd have expected something like `(user:User)-[r:USER_IS_IN_ROLE]->(role:Role)` returning `r`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neo4jClient is moving away from using `Relationship` and `Node` classes where possible, so, the good news is - you don't need to define your relationships as `: Relationship` any more! In fact, depending on how far you want to take it, you don't even need your `UserHasHomeCity` class at all!

Relationship properties are treated the same as nodes, in the sense that they are just POCO objects.

So, to create (as I'm sure you know) we do something like:

```
var userData = new User {Id = "Id-1"};
var cityData = new City {Name = "Brighton"};
var countryData = new Country {Name = "UK"};
var userHasHomeData = new HasHomeCity {Date = "April 1980"};
var generalData = new CountryRelationshipData { Area = "South Coast" };

gc.Cypher
    .Create("(country:Country {countryParams})")
    .WithParam("countryParams", countryData)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();

gc.Cypher
    .Match("(country:Country)")
    .Where((Country country) => country.Name == "UK")
    .CreateUnique("(city:City {cityParams})-[:CITY_IS_IN_COUNTRY {relParams}]->(country)")
    .WithParam("cityParams", cityData)
    .WithParam("relParams", generalData)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();

gc.Cypher
    .Match("(city:City)")
    .Where((City city) => city.Name == "Brighton")
    .Create("(user:User {userParams})-[:USER_HAS_HOME_CITY {relParams}]->(city)")
    .WithParam("userParams", userData)
    .WithParam("relParams", userHasHomeData )
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

which will give us a `(User)-[:USER_HAS_HOME_CITY]-(City)` structure.

To retrieve the relationship properties, we can use this query:

```
var query = gc.Cypher
    .Match("(user:User)-[r:USER_HAS_HOME_CITY]-(city:City)-[r1:CITY_IS_IN_COUNTRY]-(country:Country)")
    .Where((User user) => user.Id == "Id-1")
    .Return((user, city, r, country, r1) =>
        new
        {
            User = user.As<User>(),
            City = city.As<City>(),
            HasHome = r.As<HasHomeCity>(),
            Country = country.As<Country>(),
            CountryRel = r1.As<CountryRelationshipData>()
        });
```

and looping through the results (all 1 of them in this case):

```
var res = query.Results.ToList();
foreach (var result in res)
    Console.WriteLine("User ({0}) home city: {1} (which is in {2}, {3}) since {4}", result.User.Id, result.City.Name,result.CountryRel.Area,  result.Country.Name, result.HasHome.Date );
```

will give us:

```
User (Id-1) home city: Brighton (which is in South Coast, UK) since April 1980
```

as the output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction regarding the new lighter way to work with relationships! The hardest part getting started with Neo4jClient has definitely been the lack of up to date examples like this. I changed my Relationships to simple poco classes and it turned out my problem is the country part of the match statement. Do you see any obvious mistake there? The strange thing is that this query returned the country for each city perfectly well before I added the properties to the city relationship, therefore the rather misleading title of this question, sorry about that :)

Comment: I can't see anything obvious, is it just the country bit? i.e. if you match on `(user:User)-[:USER_HAS_HOME_CITY]-(homeCity:City)` does that return the right stuff?

Comment: Hi Miss J. There's a whole wiki page of query examples here: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples

Comment: Exactly Chris, without the country part the user and cities are returned correctly. With the country part included the query just return without any result, no exceptions. Have no clue here, is there another way to return second level nodes I can try?

Comment: Thanks Tatham! I used those examples to get started with the basic stuff but unfortunately there are no examples describing how to return nodes that are not directly related to my user.

Comment: To be honest, I can't see why they wouldn't work, I'll update my example code with a second layer, my only suggestion would be: Do you definitely have the data that would match in the db? i.e. if you run the query in the neo4j db is it returning data? The code I have works fine bringing back relationships, pocos etc

Comment: Thanks for all your effort Chris! I finally got it right, the problem turned out to be a silly little mistake during the creation of the user and all relationships.